# Access Claim value in gRPC server method (ASP.NET Core, .NET6) coming from JWT bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net, grpc

I have a .NET6 ASP.NET Core application that implements a gRPC service as a server.

Authentication is done using Bearer tokens (JWT). After successful authentication+authorization, a server method is invoked to deal with a request, like so:

```
[Authorize("MyPolicy", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public override Task<MyResp> MyCall(MyReq request, ServerCallContext context)
{
  // ok, I come here
}
```

Now I need to access one of the claim values that I can expect to be in the token. And I can access the token and find the value I need like so:

```
var s = context.RequestHeaders.Single(m => m.Key == "authorization").Value;
if (s.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  s = s.Remove(0, 7);
var t = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(s.Trim());
// now I can look into t.Claims
```

Fine.

But is there a better way? Before my handler becomes activated, something in the middleware must have inspected that token anyway. Is the collection of claims already available somewhere? I would expect it to be in the ServerCallContext, but I can't find it.

Comment: I think generally, you can: 1. access the JWT from the context.RequestHeaders just as you do in your example 2. use a server-side interceptor that can also see the headers in context.RequestHeaders, but can handle them in a more centralized fashion, without necessarily leaking the auth logic into your application logic. 3. you can possibly setup JWT token verification at the HTTP2 request level  in ASP.NET core, but that's pretty much a grpc-independent approach (something that would work for any HTTP requests).

Comment: Did you find a better way for this? I feel like there's got to be a better way.

Comment: No I didn't, sorry